# Php variable to angular

Tags: php, angularjs, html

Hi I'm learning angular and I don't know how to pass php variable to angular controller and then to display it by html select. I think I should do this by angular http "post" method but it doesn't work. Any idea? Please help

Html Code:

```
<div id="find" ng-controller="SelectController"> 
      <ol class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="model" disabled="disable">
            <li nya-bs-option="option in options">
                  <a>{{option.name}}</a>
             </li>
      </ol>
      <div>{{model.text}}</div>
  </div>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
     $text1 = get_field('contact1');
     $text2 = get_field('contact2');
     $text3 = get_field('contact3');
  ?>
```

Angular code:

```
app.controller('SelectController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {

    var request = $http({
    url: "../page-contact.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        data1: $text1,
        data2: $text2,
        data3: $text3
    }
        }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

$scope.options = [
  {text: data1, name: 'Option A'},
  {text: data12, name: 'Option B'},
  {text: data3, name: 'Option C'}
];

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular's Controller file,

```
$scope.var1 = "<?=$text1; ?>";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but  I don't know what to do with this 
further

Comment: You have php variable in angular $scope now. What else you want ? You are able to pass php variable in angular's controller.

Comment: It doesn't work. Console.log($scope.var) shows "<?=$text1; ?>"

Comment: Dn't console, Try {{var1}} in your HTML file and also Check if $text1 has value or not ?

Comment: $text1 has a value, maybe problem is in that the angular code is in another file...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this 
in side php:

```
$object = $params['json'];
$var = json_encode($object);
$json = json_decode($var);

echo $json->{'text1'};
echo $json->{'text2'};
echo $json->{'text3'};
```

and in angular side

```
$scope.options = [
  {text: data1, name: 'Option A'},
  {text: data12, name: 'Option B'},
  {text: data3, name: 'Option C'}
];
$http({ url: "../page-contact.php",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({ json: $scope.options })
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data) //you have data php
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });
```